# Cómo programar y visualizar arbol nenario en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo un conocimiento básico en Python pero me encontré con un problema que considero puede ser resuelto con ese lenguaje de programación.
El problema es el siguiente: hay una serie de actividades que se van ejecutando en el transcurso del día y hay unas que dependen de otras.

*Hago mención que estuve investigando un poco sobre listas enlazadas pero no encontré respuesta para conectar un nodo en su lado izquierdo con dos nodos al mismo tiempo y viceversa.*

Continuando con la misión que tengo, son aproximadamente 953 procesos. Se nos presentó que una actvidad iba a detener uno de esos proceso y necesitábamos encontrar cuáles de los procesos que dependían de él serían afectados.
Los archivos de configuración de los procesos están diseñados de la siguiente manera (archivo **run.conf**)

```
run.conf
DEPENDENCIAS= (si las tiene)
EJECUTAR=/fuentes/run.sh
```

Donde /fuentes/run.sh se ejecuta una vez concluyan exitosamente los procesos anteriores que estén en DEPENDENCIAS (si es que tiene dependencias)

Acá graficaré un ejemplo de los conf. Luego les muestro lo que he hecho hasta ahora y lo que quisiera hacer

```
actividad1.conf
DEPENDENCIAS=

actividad2.conf
DEPENDENCIAS=actividad1

actividad3.conf
DEPENDENCIAS=actividad1

actividad4.conf
DEPENDENCIAS=

actividad5.conf
DEPENDENCIAS=actividad2 actividad3 actividad4

actividad6.conf
DEPENDENCIAS=actividad5

actividad7.conf
DEPENDENCIAS=

actividad8.conf
DEPENDENCIAS=actividad7
```

armé un diccionario y logré escribir algo así (el problema que veo es que tengo que recorrer recursivamente entre *padre->proceso->padre* o *hijo->proceso->hijo* para ir por todo el camino total de un proceso determinado pero quise aplicar lo de las listas enlazadas):

```
["proceso": "actividad1","padres": [],"hijos": [actividad2 actividad3]]
["proceso": "actividad2","padres": [actividad1],"hijos": [actividad5]]
["proceso": "actividad3","padres": [actividad1],"hijos": [actividad5]]
["proceso": "actividad4","padres": [],"hijos": [actividad5]]
["proceso": "actividad5","padres": [actividad2 actividad3 actividad4],"hijos": [actividad6]]
["proceso": "actividad6","padres": [actividad5],"hijos": []]
["proceso": "actividad7","padres": [],"hijos": [actividad8]]
["proceso": "actividad8","padres": [actividad7],"hijos": []]
```

Con eso logré encontrar el primer nivel tanto de padre e hijos de cada proceso. Por ejemplo en el archivo de configuración 6, me quedaría algo como

### [image: Lo que tengo el diccionario se vería así]

Pero mi necesidad de ese nodo debería ser algo así, que me muestre su camino aguas arribas y aguas abajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si me detuviera en la actividad3 debería ser capaz de visualizar algo así, cuáles son sus padres y todos sus descendientes tal como les ejemplifico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigando por internet encontré la base de datos de grafos encontré NEO4J me la descargué a mi pc y obviamente sería lo mejor porque vi que se pueden construir nodos y sus relaciones, estando en cualquier nodo puedo ir aguas arribas y aguas abajo y sería cuestión de graficar eso en Python.
Pero me encontré con un primer problema y es que en la empresa dudan que la vayan a instalar solamente para este proceso que queremos montar.

Así que sigo con mi plan A que es construir la red con Python y ver cómo puedo graficar esos nodos de manera que en algo web podamos visualizar de un primer vistazo el proceso y el camino punta a punta al que pertenece.

Alguno ha hecho algo similar, alguna idea, sugerencia o recomendación?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que implementar los recorridos de de arboles, espeficicamente el `recorrido entre-orden` te permite obtener la solucion que deseas. (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorrido_de_%C3%A1rboles)

Para usar arboles puedes usar estas librerias [Tinytree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tinytree) o [Treedict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/treedict)